# Reading/Writing Objects using Serializable

Tags: java, javafx

so I have an object, a Hotel, which implements Serializable. I am using an FX application that has many buttons. The FX application has a hotel object, as a field, which is the object that I want to read/write.

1. Is it read before write? or write before read? and should it be in the start method?
2. Do you have the read/write methods right next to each other on startup? Or should I have a button to close/save the application, and have it write the object to a file (and read it on startup)?

Here's what I have so far, and I believe it's writing successfully, but it is not reading.

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

       try {
        ObjectOutputStream oosoos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("hotelRooms.dat"));
        oosoos.writeObject(hotel);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }   
      //  Hotel tempHotel;
         try {
    ObjectInputStream iisiis = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("hotelRooms.dat"));
    hotel = (Hotel)iisiis.readObject();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ffe ) {
        System.out.println(ffe.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Describe the desired lifecycle of a `Hotel` object and what you'd like to do with the data/where you get the data from. Without this info there's no way to choose the right/a good approach.

Comment: @fabian Of course. I apologize. A hotel has many hotel rooms, and the application allows the user to enter a guest information and book a room. https://imgur.com/a/34qABWl This is a picture of my application. The hotel has 2 arraylists, one of HotelRoom, and one of Reservation. The application doesn't close and will continue to work until there are no more open rooms.

Comment: That describes the structure of the `Hotel`class but not it's lifecycle. The lifecycle would be more important for this question though.You should describe where the input for creating a `Hotel` initially comes from, how the user modifies the data and when this data is loaded/saved.There is no "correct" way to save the data.You need to decide if you want to save the data on every modification,wait for the application to finish to automatically save the data or let the user choose when to save by interacting with the GUI.BTW:[Edit] the question to include information important to all answerers.

Comment: @fabian I updated the question. A hotel is instantiated in my FX application. Basically, when a user fills out the form correctly, it adds a reservation and makes one of the hotelrooms in the hotelroom arraylist, not vacant. So, the user modifies a hotel by creating/updating reservations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used FX before, but I think I might be able to help, by making some assumptions...

I assume that your start() method is a lifecycle method defined by some FX class and you need to load the Hotel object when the application starts. Presumably you then have some sort of finish() method where you want to save the latest version of the Hotel object for later..?

If so, you need to 'read()' the object in the start() method and 'write()' the Hotel in the finish() method.

The problem in your code snippet is that you are trying to do both in the start() method. This has all manner of potential issues, not least of which is that your write() method needs to flush the stream (causing the data to actually be written to the file) and you probably then need to close the output stream before the input stream will be allowed to read.

Probably.

It might just be that if you call

```
oosoos.close();   // this will flush the stream
```

...after

```
oosoos.writeObject(hotel);
```

then the intput stream will successfully read the object.
However, you really need to split this code up as I mentioned previously - the code that you have posted is pointless; you write the Hotel object to the file and then read it back... you could just use the object that you wrote to file, without ever reading it back in...

Hope this helps and apologies if I have misunderstood, due to lack of knowledge of FX.

Comment: Most likely the suitable "`finish`" method is [`Application.stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--) or some event handler e.g. when a user activates some button.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was split up the read/write. I have it so it reads/inputs on startup, and when they click a button to create a reservation, it writes the current hotel object to the file.